# How do you declare partials for arrays w.r.t scalars, and vice versa?

Tags: openmdao

I'm trying to implement this calculation:

[image]

With the following code:

```
class BendingMoment(om.ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):

        self.add_input('cableForce', units='N')
        self.add_input('cableAngle', units='rad')
        self.add_input('cablePosition', units='m')
        self.add_input('FArray', units='N/m')
        self.add_input('zArray', units='m')
        self.add_input('wingspan', units='m')

        self.add_output('MArray', units='N*m')

        self.declare_partials('MArray', ['FArray', 'cableForce', 'cableAngle', 'cablePosition', 'wingspan', 'zArray'])


    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):

        Fc = inputs['cableForce']
        ang = inputs['cableAngle']
        FArray = inputs['FArray']
        zArray = inputs['zArray']
        b = inputs['wingspan']
        a = inputs['cablePosition']

        M = np.zeros_like(zArray)

        for i in range(len(zArray)):
            M[i] = np.trapz((zArray[i:]-zArray[i])*FArray[i:], zArray[i:]) - (0.5*b - a - zArray[i])*Fc*np.sin(ang)

        outputs['MArray'] = M
```

Where Fc, ang, b, a are scalars; FArray, zArray are arrays.

How would you declare partials for M w.r.t a scalar, i.e Fc?

And if there was a code that took an array and summed or integrated it to create a scalar value, how would you declare the partials for that? What exactly would the Jacobian look like for both of these cases?

Comment: The code you provided isn't runnable. Your equation for `M[i]` has a scalar valued LHS, but a vector valued RHS (i.e. `zArray[i:]-zArray[i]` returns a vector of varying length as you loop over i). 

please correct your code and edit your question with at least a full component, but preferably also a bit of code to actually execute it.

Comment: Do you have a reference you can point to for this formula?  You're setting each element of M to an array value `M[i] = (zArray[i:]-zArray[i])*FArray[i] - ...`, which doesn't seem to be correct.

If at all possible, write these equations out in vector form and avoid the for loop.  Python will be far faster if you use numpy's vectorized approach.

Comment: Sorry about the code not being runnable; I'm not good with using arrays to calculate integrals/represent functions evaluated at points yet. Added the formula to the post. Hopefully the code is correct now.

Comment: I've managed to write the output as a vector-valued function, but it still relies on slicing arrays (for trapezium rule), and I'm not sure how to express partial derivatives to sliced arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an output `Y` of size (n0,n1) and an input `X` of size (m0, m1) --- both are 2D arrays to make things a bit more general. Then the size of the jacobian that you provide to OpenMDAO for derivatives of `Y` with respect to `X` will be a matrix of size (n0*n1, m0*m1) ---i.e. n0*n1 rows and m0*m1 columns.

You always get the number of rows equal to the flattened size of the array (and the rows will be in the same order as the flattened array). It works similarly for inputs.

The best way to look at the partial derivative Jacobian, and to see if you got the derivative right is to use the [check_partials method](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.0.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/basic_check_partials.html) which will compare your analytic derivatives to the approximate ones. You can use this, even if you haven't defined your derivatives yet --- you'll just get all zeros, which you can check by commenting out the `compute_partials` in the following code:

```
import numpy as np

import openmdao.api as om

class BendingMoment(om.ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):

        self.add_input('cableForce', units='N')
        self.add_input('cableAngle', units='rad')
        self.add_input('cablePosition', units='m')
        self.add_input('wingspan', units='m')

        self.add_input('FArray', units='N/m', shape=3)
        self.add_input('zArray', units='m', shape=3)

        self.add_output('MArray', units='N*m', shape=3)

        self.declare_partials('MArray', ['FArray', 'cableForce', 'cableAngle', 'cablePosition', 'wingspan', 'zArray'])


    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):

        Fc = inputs['cableForce']
        ang = inputs['cableAngle']
        FArray = inputs['FArray']
        zArray = inputs['zArray']
        b = inputs['wingspan']
        a = inputs['cablePosition']

        M = outputs['MArray']

        size = len(zArray)

        # we can use np.trapz, only because we can "guess" how its implemented so that we can differentiate it
        # for i in range(size):
        #     M[i] = np.trapz((zArray[i:]-zArray[i])*FArray[i:], zArray[i:]) - (0.5*b - a - zArray[i])*Fc*np.sin(ang)

        # equivalent code to np.trapz written out with for loops explicitly. This code would be slower to run,
        # so we'll leave the call to the numpy function, but we'll look at this to compute the partial derivatives
        M[:] = 0 # clear out the array 
        for i in range(size): 
            for j in range(i, size-1): 
                M[i] += (zArray[j+1] - zArray[j]) * ((zArray[j] - zArray[i])*FArray[j] + (zArray[j+1] - zArray[i])*FArray[j+1])/2.

                # # note that for i=j, you get a special case
                # if i == j: 
                #     M[i] += (zArray[j+1] - zArray[j]) * (zArray[j+1] - zArray[i])*FArray[j+1]/2.
                # else: 
                #     M[i] += (zArray[j+1] - zArray[j]) * ((zArray[j] - zArray[i])*FArray[j] + (zArray[j+1] - zArray[i])*FArray[j+1])/2.

            M[i] -= (0.5*b - a - zArray[i])*Fc*np.sin(ang)


    def compute_partials(self, inputs, J): 

        Fc = inputs['cableForce']
        ang = inputs['cableAngle']
        FArray = inputs['FArray']
        zArray = inputs['zArray']
        b = inputs['wingspan']
        a = inputs['cablePosition']

        size = len(zArray)

        # We can't easily compute the partials for this component, 
        # because we don't know exactly what np.trapz does.

        for i in range(size): 
            for j in range(i, size-1): 
                J['MArray', 'FArray'][i,j] += (zArray[j+1] - zArray[j]) * (zArray[j] - zArray[i])/2.
                J['MArray', 'FArray'][i,j+1] += (zArray[j+1] - zArray[j]) * (zArray[j+1] - zArray[i])/2.


                term1 = (zArray[j+1] - zArray[j])
                term2 = ((zArray[j] - zArray[i])*FArray[j] + (zArray[j+1] - zArray[i])*FArray[j+1])/2.
                # z portion
                if i == j: # z == Array[j] -- special case
                    J['MArray', 'zArray'][i,i] += -term2 - term1 * (FArray[j+1])/2.
                else: 
                    J['MArray', 'zArray'][i,i] += -term1*(FArray[j+1]+FArray[j+1])/2.                
                    J['MArray', 'zArray'][i,j] += - term2 + term1*FArray[j]/2.                
                J['MArray', 'zArray'][i,j+1] += term2 + term1*FArray[j+1]/2.

            # account for the additional term with zArray in it
            J['MArray', 'zArray'][i,i] += Fc*np.sin(ang)

            J['MArray', 'cableAngle'][i] = -(0.5*b - a - zArray[i])*Fc*np.cos(ang)
            J['MArray', 'cableForce'][i] = -(0.5*b - a - zArray[i])*np.sin(ang)
            J['MArray', 'cablePosition'][i] = a*Fc*np.sin(ang)
            J['MArray', 'wingspan'][i] = -0.5*b*Fc*np.sin(ang)


if __name__ == '__main__': 

    p = om.Problem()

    p.model.add_subsystem('bending', BendingMoment(), promotes=['*'])

    p.setup()

    # note: leaving the zArray with the default value means it would be [1,1,1] 
    #       which is non-physical, and will be a degenerate point to check the partials around. 
    #       So we'll set it to a linear distribution
    p['bending.zArray'] = np.linspace(0,10,3)

    p.run_model()


    p.check_partials()
```

gives this output:

```
----------------------------------
Component: BendingMoment 'bending'
----------------------------------
  bending: 'MArray' wrt 'FArray'
    Forward Magnitude : 3.750000e+01
         Fd Magnitude : 3.750000e+01 (fd:forward)
    Absolute Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 6.343738e-09

    Relative Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 1.691664e-10

    Raw Forward Derivative (Jfor)
[[ 0.  25.  25. ]
 [ 0.   0.  12.5]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ]]

    Raw FD Derivative (Jfd)
[[ 0.         24.99999999 25.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         12.5       ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  bending: 'MArray' wrt 'cableAngle'
    Forward Magnitude : 6.410044e+00
         Fd Magnitude : 6.410039e+00 (fd:forward)
    Absolute Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 4.991817e-06 *

    Relative Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 7.787499e-07

    Raw Forward Derivative (Jfor)
[[0.27015115]
 [2.97166268]
 [5.67317421]]

    Raw FD Derivative (Jfd)
[[0.27015094]
 [2.97166037]
 [5.67316979]]

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  bending: 'MArray' wrt 'cableForce'
    Forward Magnitude : 9.983052e+00
         Fd Magnitude : 9.983052e+00 (fd:forward)
    Absolute Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 3.700281e-09

    Relative Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 3.706563e-10

    Raw Forward Derivative (Jfor)
[[0.42073549]
 [4.62809042]
 [8.83544534]]

    Raw FD Derivative (Jfd)
[[0.42073549]
 [4.62809042]
 [8.83544534]]

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  bending: 'MArray' wrt 'cablePosition'
    Forward Magnitude : 1.457470e+00
         Fd Magnitude : 1.457470e+00 (fd:forward)
    Absolute Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 9.138199e-10

    Relative Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 6.269904e-10

    Raw Forward Derivative (Jfor)
[[0.84147098]
 [0.84147098]
 [0.84147098]]

    Raw FD Derivative (Jfd)
[[0.84147099]
 [0.84147099]
 [0.84147099]]

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  bending: 'MArray' wrt 'wingspan'
    Forward Magnitude : 7.287352e-01
         Fd Magnitude : 7.287353e-01 (fd:forward)
    Absolute Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 3.834701e-09

    Relative Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 5.262132e-09

    Raw Forward Derivative (Jfor)
[[-0.42073549]
 [-0.42073549]
 [-0.42073549]]

    Raw FD Derivative (Jfd)
[[-0.4207355 ]
 [-0.42073549]
 [-0.42073549]]

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  bending: 'MArray' wrt 'zArray'
    Forward Magnitude : 1.506254e+01
         Fd Magnitude : 1.506254e+01 (fd:forward)
    Absolute Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 9.989117e-07

    Relative Error (Jfor  - Jfd) : 6.631761e-08

    Raw Forward Derivative (Jfor)
[[-9.15852902  0.         10.        ]
 [ 0.         -4.15852902  5.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.84147098]]

    Raw FD Derivative (Jfd)
[[-9.15852851  0.         10.00000049]
 [ 0.         -4.15852852  5.0000005 ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.84147099]]
```

Note that the code given here is correct, but not necessarily fast. Once you have correct answers, it is a lot easier to vectorize them. I find it very difficult to work with the faster, vectorized code first. I almost always keep the slow python-for-loop version of the code commented out along side the vectorized code

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is there a more elegant (openMDAO-idiomatic?) way to handle integration?

Comment: I also notice that you used the dense partials specification. FArray/MArray are both (1200x1) arrays, so would this still be appropriate?

Comment: The way you did the integration is fine, IMO. If you used a fancier numpy integration routine (e.g. gaussian quadrature) that would also be fine... but you need to know how to differentiate it. So using the library function won't save you from having to understand the integration routine. 
For this problem, the ('MArray' wrt 'zArray') and ('MArray' wrt 'FArray') should both be sparse (since they are upper triangular, and only 50% of their entries will be filled). You'll get better performance out of the direct solver that way. The others are dense, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still having issue wrapping my head around what size my input vector is, since the inputs are two arrays of size 1200, 1; and three scalars. Is it (1200, 5)? Do the extra entries get filled with the scalars or zeroes? Let me know if this should be a new question.

Comment: think of each pair of (<output>,<input>) as a unique sub-jacobian. You only need to think about the size of each of those, and not the jacobian of the component as a hole. Each sub-jac is of size (flattened_output , flattened_input)